# Who is the old man that finds out where Andrew Cunanan is hiding?

Tags: american-crime-story, the-assassination-of-gianni-versace

In episode 9 of ***The Assassination of Gianni Versace: American Crime Story***, an old man receives a phone call and visits the boathouse where Andrew Cunanan has been hiding for several days. This old man notices the boathouse has been broken in and pulls out a pistol and starts searching this boathouse. Andrew fires a shot in the air to scare off this old man, who calls the police and FBI right away.

Who is this old man? What does he do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[TV Guide explains](https://www.tvguide.com/news/assassination-gianni-versace-american-crime-story-recap/):

> Did Andrew fire a warning shot for the man who came looking inside the
>   houseboat?
>
> Yes. **The man in charge of watching over the houseboat** — which by the
>   way belonged to a man who ran gay bathhouses in Las Vegas and is
>   believed to be a place Andrew knew he could hide — alerted authorities
>   when he went to check on it and noticed the front door was
>   compromised. "His suspicions mounted as he and his wife entered,
>   because all the lights were on and the drapes, which were always open,
>   were drawn," ***Vulgar Favors*** says. Cushions had been pulled off the sofa
>   and made into a bed on the floor with a blanket, and a chair had been
>   turned over as if to form a barricade. As he pulled out his gun, he
>   heard a loud shot from the second-floor master bedroom. He and his
>   wife ran outside and hid in the bushes and he called his son, who
>   called the police.

*Vulgar Favors* is the book the series is based on:

> Though the Versace family contends FX's series is fictitious, the
>   series is based on the book *Vulgar Favors* by investigative journalist
>   **Maureen Orth** — a *Vanity Fair* correspondent who spoke to more than 400
>   people in researching her exhaustively detailed book.